# Text field allow only numbers and decimals by user input in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a text field which need to allow only numbers and decimals by user.

And also need to set minimum and maximum value.

```
<td ng-class="{ 'has-error' : eForm.marks_{{$index}}.$dirty && eForm.marks_{{$index}}.$error.required }">                                          
    <input type="text" name="marks_{{$index}}" ng-model="data.marks" placeholder="% of Marks" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!eEditMode[$index]"  min="1" max="100" ng-required="true">
    <span ng-show="eForm.marks_{{$index}}.$dirty && eForm.marks_{{$index}}.$error.required" class="help-block">Marks is required</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the number input:

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
           min="0" max="99" required>
```

For more details: [input components in ng / input[number]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Comment: But it is like dropdown selection but my requirement is : The number need to be entered by the user and that field should accept only number and decimal

Comment: Please visit the doc page and take a look at the example at the bottom of the page ! It's not like a dropdown, the user can enter a number and the field accept only numbers

Comment: Yes i saw. its like selection menu. But i want a text box which will allow only numbers and decimal values

Comment: I'm confused ! what selection menu ? could you please send me a picture ? and what browser are you using ?

Comment: As mentioned above example (input components in ng / input[number]) i am getting arrow in left-side of the field. I am able to enter the value but my controller is not accepting the range value.

Comment: You can use the same `input type="text"` and need to handle the same(integer allowed and min and max value) in the JS file using regular expression otherwise that css you have to change explicitly if you are using the `input type="number"`. IF not the scroll will always appear for number type

Comment: I tried I made some changes in jsfiddle. But issue i am facing is i am not able to set maximum value

Comment: are you looking for number of digits or maximum value, how you want the value?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**Controller :**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    });

    app.directive("marksRegex", function() {

      var regexp;
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          regexp = /^([0-9]([0-9]([\.]([0-9]([0-9]?)?)?)?)?)?$/;
          var char;
          elem.bind("keypress", function(event) {
            if (event.which == 8) return;
            char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
            if (!regexp.test(elem.val() + char))
              event.preventDefault();
          })
        }
      }

    });
```

**HTML :**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <label>Marks %:</label>
        <input type="text" marks-regex>
      </div>
    </div>
```